# Issues drawing a line in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I already have a program that can draw textured objects. I want to draw debug lines, so I tried to copy the same sort of drawing process I use for sprites to draw a line. I made a new fragment and vertex shader because lines aren't going to be textured and having a different debug shader could be useful.

My system continues to work if I try to draw a line, but the line doesn't draw. I tried to write code similar to working code for my sprites, but clearly I've missed something or made a mistake.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 uniformView;
uniform mat4 uniformProjection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = uniformProjection * uniformView * vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 uniformColor;

void main()
{
    color = uniformColor;
}
```

Drawing Code:

```
void debugDrawLine(glm::vec3 startPoint, glm::vec3 endPoint, glm::vec3 color, Shader debugShader)
{
  GLint transformLocation, colorLocation;
  GLfloat lineCoordinates[] = { startPoint.x, startPoint.y,
                               endPoint.x, endPoint.y};
  GLuint vertexArray, vertexBuffer;

  glLineWidth(5.0f);

  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
  glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

  glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

  debugShader.Use();

  //Copies the Vertex data into the buffer
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(lineCoordinates), lineCoordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    2,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    2*sizeof(GL_FLOAT), // stride
    (GLvoid*)0            // array buffer offset
    );


  //Sends the sprite's color information in the the shader 
  colorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(debugShader.Program, "uniformColor");
  glUniform4f(colorLocation, 1.0f, color.x, color.y, color.z);

  //Activates Vertex Position Information
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

  // Draw the line
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: It's probably the same size, but in the arguments to `glVertexAttribPointer()`, that should be `sizeof(GLfloat)`, not `sizeof(GL_FLOAT)`.

Comment: Are you sure color.z is not 0? I suggest changing color = uniformColor; to color = vec4(1,1,0,1); in the frag shader to be sure. Also try moving your enableVertArray before your glVertexAttribPointer

Comment: I did fix the GL_FLOAT issue, thanks. As I tried the color and enabling the vertArray first but neither of those fixes worked.

Answer (score 0):

Line widths greater than 1 are not allowed in core profile. Does the line render if you set the size to 1

Comment: unfortunately not. However, that was causing error 1281 from glGetError.